# Jquery content tab showing white space

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have used a jquery content tab plugin in my project. there is 6 tabs with content (Company, The founders, Team, Accolades, Careers, Philosophy). When I click Company tab after clicking any other tab there is a white space over the content (in Chrome). How can I remove that white space?? here is my link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `float:left` in the container but miss clearfix.
You can add `overflow:auto` to `company` element or add clear div.
And what Gaurav said is right, you should not use ul to be the container.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup

```
<ul id="company" style="display: block;">
    <div class="about_logo_area">
        <div class="pic_categry_info_img2 full_img">
            <img src="images/new/flutura_about_logo.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="about_logo_txt_area">
        <p><strong>Flutura</strong> is a niche Big data analytics solutions company based out of <strong>Palo Alto</strong> (Development Centre in Bangalore) with a vision to transform operational outcomes by monetizing machine data. It does so by triangulating economic impactful signals from fragmented data pools. The name <strong>Flutura</strong> stands for butterfly; inspired by nature's greatest transformation from a caterpillar to a butterfly. We are obsessed with Trust and Transformation and align our daily lives to these core principles.
<strong>Flutura</strong> has recently been identified as one of the top 20 most promising Big Data start-ups across the globe by leading analyst magazine <strong>CIO Review</strong>. <strong>Flutura</strong> has also been featured on Gigaom reports on Big data + M2M in energy sector. <strong>Flutura</strong> was also the winner at TechSparks, where 800 innovative startups were evaluated.</p>
        <p><strong>Flutura</strong> is funded by Silicon Valley’s leading VC fund The Hive (based in Palo Alto) which primarily invests in big data companies worldwide.</p>
    </div>
</ul>
```

`div` is not allowed as a direct child of `ul`. You can [validate your page with W3C](http://validator.w3.org) or check [the corresponding article on W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element):

> #### 4.5.6 The ul element
>
> **Categories**
>   [Flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#flow-content).
>
> **Contexts in which this element can be used:**
>   Where [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#flow-content) is expected.
>
> **Content model:**
>   Zero or more li elements.
>
> **Content attributes:**
>   [Global attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#global-attributes)
>
> **DOM interface:**
>   `interface HTMLUListElement : HTMLElement {};`

The only element that may be a child of `<ul>` is `<li>`.

[HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#h-10.2):

```
<!ELEMENT UL - - (LI)+                 -- unordered list -->
```

(See also [how to read a content model definition in a DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.3.1))

[HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-ul-element.html#the-ul-element):

> Content model:
>   Zero or more li elements.

To add to it while a div inside a li is valid, a div inside a dl, dd, or dt is not! (Note that this is only in HTML 4 and earlier)

Also, if you are not using HTML5 instead XHTML1, (here I can see your using but just to add more information)

If you look at [xhtml1-strict.dtd](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd), you'll see

```
<!ELEMENT li %Flow;>
<!ENTITY % Flow "(#PCDATA | %block; | form | %inline; | %misc;)*">
<!ENTITY % block
     "p | %heading; | div | %lists; | %blocktext; | fieldset | table">
```

Thus `div`, `p` etc. can be inside `li` (according to XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD from w3.org).